# Remove part of a sentence after specific character in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in pandas full of sentences. In each of those sentences, I'm trying to remove part of a sentence after a word "in". Example:

Current form: "Mary has a lot of furniture inside her house, where she lives with her parents and her boyfriend in Maryland"

Desired form: "Mary has a lot of furniture inside her house, where she lives with her parents and her boyfriend"

I have tried multiple solutions, however in each case the sentence gets separated after any instance of a string "in", even when it's inside a word. So currently, my output is this:  "Mary has a lot of furniture". That's because the word inside contains the string "in"

This is what I currently have and its not producing a desired output:

```
 df['split'] = df.sentences.apply(lambda x: "in".join(x.split("in", 1)[:1]))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.split` and split on the word `in` if it has a whitespace before and after it.

```
df['split'] = df['sentences'].str.split('\sin\s').str[0]
```

**Output**

```
0    Mary has a lot of furniture inside her house, where she lives with her parents and her boyfriend
Name: sentences, dtype: object
```

---

Or using word boundaries as [Zachary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57245007/remove-part-of-a-sentence-after-specific-character-in-pandas#comment100990786_57245031) suggests in the comments:

```
df['split'] = df['sentences'].str.split(r'\bin\b').str[0]
```

Comment: Using \b in the regex should be more correct, instead of \s. In case the "in" is surrounded by punctuation.

Comment: df['sentences'].str.split(r'\bin\b').str[0]

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, you just need to add an extra space before and after the word `in` like this `' in '`:

```
df['split'] = df.sentences.apply(lambda x: " in ".join(x.split(" in ", 1)[:1]))
```

Output:

```
Mary has a lot of furniture inside her house, where she lives with her parents and her boyfriend
```